# update clone git repository it remove my work from clone git?

Tags: git, github

if we clone a repository what would happen when owner of repository update it, It remove my git work/ changes from the clone git?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not pushing the wrong folder? 
This has happend to me, I had the repo set to the wrong folder so I kept pushing an empty project.